# Solve a differential equation using Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, physics, fourier-series

Assume I have a second order differential equation $\ddot{x} = F(x,\dot{x})$ (or an equivalent equation of first order) and that I know there is a periodic solution to it (for simplicity's sake, assume the period is $1$).

Is there a way to solve this kind of problem passing through Fourier series? My Idea would be to try to rephrase this as a differential equation of the Fourier coefficients and solve for an equilibrium (i.e. a periodic solution). Is this possible?

The problem which gave me the idea is the following: There is an electron (point particle, mass $m$, charge $e$) in a space filled by a planar EM-wave, so $\vec{E} = (E\sin(kx-\omega t),0,0)$ and $\vec{B} = (0,B\sin(kx-\omega t),0)$ where $cB=E$. The electron is excited by the wave and emits EM-radiation. Find the emitted radiation.

Now, the Lorenz force gives us the equation $m\ddot{x} = e(\vec{E}+\dot{x}\wedge\vec{B})$ to solve. Note: in the problem I can neglige the contribution of the magnetic field (since $B\ll E$), so I get standard oscillatory motion.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the function $F$ looks like? Fourier transforms don't generally play well with function compositions. But there are exceptions.

Comment: As I wrote a couple of lines further down, the specific case in which I am interested is $\ddot{x} = \frac{e}{m}(\vec{E}+\dot{x}\wedge\vec{B})$.

Comment: @WillieWong: By the way, since I want a periodic function, probably Fourier series are better suited for the problem...